# Anyone Can Register

Tags: wp-admin, users

Please explain what is the purpose or intent of the setting "Anyone can register"...is this a backend setting or does it make my personal information available?

Answer (score 2):

It simply allows the general public to create a new WordPress user. Whether or not they can see other user's user information depends on the default [role](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/) assigned to new users and any capabilities assigned.

Unless you change the default role setting, new users will be assigned [the Subscriber role which only has the `read` capability](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#subscriber) by default.

[The read capability](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#read) only grants access to an almost entirely stripped down dashboard screen and their own user profile.

You can refer to [this table](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#capability-vs-role-table) for the default roles/capabilities assignment. In general, any role below Administrator cannot access the general Users screen in the dashboard (or the `/wp-json/wp/v2/users` REST endpoint) for not having [the `list_users` capability](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#list_users).

Try it yourself: create new Subscriber user through the dashboard, then log in as that user and see what you have access to.